# Sql split date range into weeks and then calculate percentage on result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've looked around and there are similar questions to my own, buy my use case is slightly different. I can manage basic sql but i could use some work.

So my use case is i have a line chart report that i need to create a stored proc for. I have a checkin table as shown below. What i need to do is calculate the hours spent at each location type, and then seperate it per week for the line chart.

[image]

I have done something similar for a pie chart. The procedure is not pretty though.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Report_TimeSpentAtBase]   
@startdate as DateTime,
@endDate as DateTime = null,
@teamID as uniqueidentifier = null,
@userID as uniqueidentifier = null

AS
BEGIN   
    SELECT 
    LocationType,
    Sum(DATEDIFF(minute, InAt, OutAt)) Seconds
    FROM CheckIns
        INNER JOIN Locations ON Locations.Id = CheckIns.Location_ID
        INNER JOIN [System].[Users] ON CheckIns.User_Id = [System].[Users].Id
    WHERE 
    DATEPART(dw, InAt) NOT IN (1, 7) AND
    InAt >= @startdate AND
    OutAt IS NOT NULL AND
    DATEPART(dw, OutAt) NOT IN (1, 7) AND
    (@teamID IS NULL OR [System].[Users].Team_ID = @teamID) AND 
    (@userID IS NULL OR [System].[Users].ID = @userID) AND
    (@endDate IS NULL OR OutAt <= @endDate)
    GROUP BY LocationType 
END
GO
```

So for clarity a user checks into a location, i record that in the checkin table. I then use the checkin/out time to calculate the hours they have spent at that location. The line chart i am using requires this format.

[image]

So ideally i should end up with a TimeSpentAtBaseRow for each location type, and then a series for each week.

I am not expecting someone to write this for me, i could just do with a push in the right direction. Thank you for any help or guidance.

Examples of data for each table:

[image]

Location type is just an enum

[image]

and the checkin table

[image]

Lastly the existing stored procedures result look like:

```
LocationType | Minutes
----------------------
Base         | 100
Hospital     | 200
```

So the total minutes for each checkin for each location type.

EDIT

So my current progress so far is.

```
WITH dates as 
(
    select number, DATEADD(day, number, '20170101') as dt
    from master..spt_values
    where number between 0 and 1000 AND TYPE ='P'
)
SELECT 
    l.LocationType,
    d.dt,
    Sum(DATEDIFF(minute, InAt, OutAt)) as mins
FROM Checkins ci
    INNER JOIN Locations l ON l.Id = ci.Location_ID
JOIN dates d
    on d.dt between ci.InAt and ci.OutAt
GROUP BY
    d.dt, l.LocationType
```

Comment: While you have provided a respectful amount of description, unfortunately it is not what is most helpful to an answerer. It would be far better to provide a few example rows for each table you have, and the resulting rows of your select query.

Comment: would it make it easier if you had a 'weeks' table with the start time of each week in it?  You could cross join the week table to the location table, then for each week and location, you could join to the checkins that have time during that week.  They you could calculate that time (maybe it would be partial if they checked in and out over a week boundary) then you could group and summarise.  Your 'weeks' table can be a static table (to get things going) but ultimately you might want to generate it dynamically using WITH

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis ive edited the question and added some example data, and the result of the current stored proc.

Comment: Hey can you paste your script in your question also instead of just the pictures? :P

Comment: @connorg98 yer no problem :)

Comment: @Tony_89 Instead of trying to calculate weeks from the dates, use a Date orCalendar table with week numbers as [shown here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/). This makes aggregating by week in a date range trivial and fast, as the server is able to use indexes defined on the date columns. Using `DATEPART` will force the server to scan the *entire* table to calculate week numbers before filtering them.  BTW screenshots aren't helpful (at all) in a question. They can't be copied, compiled and they don't show the data types

Comment: @Tony_89 if you care about tiems as well you could add a Time or Shift table

Comment: Yer i like the idea of the calendar table, we will have other similar queries in the future so it makes sense to have a reusable aspect to it.

Comment: Tony, first, be informed that images are not too welcome in this site, since they can't have their text copied from. Second, tell me if I understand correct: You want a table with columns  location,week,time spent at that location within the week. Is that correct?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Yer that's my mistake, i don't usually ask sql questions, i will edit my question. So ideally the result i want is to have a stored proc where i can pass a start and end date. Take that date and split it into weeks. Then calculate the time spent at that location for each week. So yer the result would have the columns, locationtype, week, and time spent at that location within the week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the general idea.  The bounds checking may need a little tweaking for edge cases.

```
/*
Set up data
*/
declare @startDate datetime = '07/01/2018'; -- first day you want included
declare @endDate datetime = '07/15/2018'; -- day AFTER the last you want included

declare @location table (locationId int, locationName varchar(100));
declare @log table (logId int, locationId int, checkIn datetime, checkOut datetime);

insert @location values 
    (1, 'Location 1'), 
    (2, 'Location 2');

insert @log values 
    (1, 1, '07/07/2018 20:00:00', '07/08/2018 06:00:00'), 
    (2, 1, '07/08/2018 20:00:00', '07/09/2018 06:00:00'), 
    (3, 1, '07/09/2018 20:00:00', '07/10/2018 06:00:00')
    ;

/* 
Summary by location
*/
select  loc.locationId ,
        loc.locationName ,
        SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, log.checkIn, log.checkOut)) as minutes
from    @location loc
inner join @log log on log.locationId = loc.locationId
group by loc.locationId ,
        loc.locationName
;

/*
Summary by location and week
*/
with
    -- List of weeks.  There are other ways to do this.
    weeks as (
        select  @startDate as startDate ,
                dateadd(week, 1, @startDate) as endDate
        union all
        select  endDate /*as startDate*/ ,
                dateadd(week, 1, endDate) /* as endDate*/
        from    weeks
        where   endDate < @endDate
    ) ,
    -- Determine how much time each log entry is in each week.
    logWeeks as (
        select  log.locationId ,
                w.startDate as week ,
                datediff(
                    minute ,
                    case when log.checkIn >= w.startDate then log.checkIn else w.startDate end ,
                    case when log.checkOut <= w.endDate then log.checkOut else w.endDate end
                ) as minutes
        from    @log log
        inner join weeks w
                on log.checkIn < w.endDate
                and log.checkOut >= w.startDate
    )
-- Summarize.
select  loc.locationId ,
        loc.locationName ,
        lw.week ,
        sum(lw.minutes)
from    @location loc
inner join logWeeks lw
        on lw.locationId = loc.locationId
group by loc.locationId ,
        loc.locationName ,
        lw.week
order by loc.locationId ,
        lw.week
;
```

Comment: Thank you, that is pretty much i needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution I created for my requirement, which divides the date range into given intervals excluding weekends.

I created 1 procedure which divides the date range into given intervals.
Also, created 1 method to check if the date is weekend and return the next/previous weekdays based on flag value.

Below is the procedure

```
Alter PROCEDURE DateToInterval
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@start datetime,
@end datetime,
@interval int 
AS
BEGIN

declare @start_run as datetime
declare @end_run as datetime
declare @counter as int

--temp table to store interval 
create table #tempinterval(
StartDate datetime,
EndDate datetime,
IntervalCounter varchar(20) 
)

--update start, end date if it is weekend
set @start_run=DBTest.dbo.Check_Weekend_And_Update_With_WeekDays(@start,'add')
set @end_run=DBTest.dbo.Check_Weekend_And_Update_With_WeekDays(@start,'remove')
set @end=DBTest.dbo.Check_Weekend_And_Update_With_WeekDays(@end,'remove')
set @counter=1

--select @start_run as 'start', @end as 'end'

While(@end_run <= @end)
Begin
        --select 'loop'
        --adding interval on start date
        set @end_run = DATEADD(DAY, @interval-1, cast(@start_run as datetime))  

        if(@end_run > @end) 
            BEGIN
                set @end_run=@end
            END

        --to check if it is weekend and replace it week next weekdays
        set @end_run=DBTest.dbo.Check_Weekend_And_Update_With_WeekDays(@end_run,'add')

        insert into #tempinterval(StartDate,EndDate,IntervalCounter) values(@start_run,@end_run,'Interval '+ cast(@counter as varchar))

        set @end_run=DATEADD(DAY, 1, cast(@end_run as datetime))    

        --update end date if it is weekend
        set @end_run=DBTest.dbo.Check_Weekend_And_Update_With_WeekDays(@end_run,'add')

        set @start_run=@end_run
        set @counter =@counter + 1 

END


select * from #tempinterval

 END
 GO
```

Method to check and convert weekend into weekdays

```
Alter FUNCTION Check_Weekend_And_Update_With_WeekDays
(

 @date date,
 @flag varchar(10) --flag to add or removed dates to get the weekdays
 )
RETURNS datetime
 AS
 BEGIN
 -- Declare the return variable here
 DECLARE @ResultVar date


--1 (Sunday) or 7 (Saturday)
IF DATEPART(W, @date) in (1,7)
    BEGIN
        IF(DATEPART(W, @date)=1) --IF sunday
            BEGIN
                IF(@flag='add')
                    BEGIN                   
                        set @date=DATEADD(DAY, 1, cast(@date as datetime))  
                    END
                ELSE 
                    BEGIN
                        set @date=DATEADD(DAY, -2, cast(@date as datetime)) 
                    END
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                IF(@flag='add') --If Saturday
                    BEGIN           
                        set @date=DATEADD(DAY, 2, cast(@date as datetime))  
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        set @date=DATEADD(DAY, -1, cast(@date as datetime)) 
                    END
            END             

    END

        set @ResultVar=@date


-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @ResultVar

END
GO
```